# Установка библиотеки mongodb / mongo-php-library в Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, mongodb, php7.2

`composer require mongodb/mongodb`

Using version ^1.5 for mongodb/mongodb
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
`- mongodb/mongodb v1.5.x-dev requires ext-mongodb ^1.6 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb has the wrong version (1.3.4) installed.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.6.x-dev requires ext-mongodb ^1.7 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb has the wrong version (1.3.4) installed.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.5.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.6 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb has the wrong version (1.3.4) installed.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.5.1 requires ext-mongodb ^1.6 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb has the wrong version (1.3.4) installed.
    - mongodb/mongodb 1.5.0 requires ext-mongodb ^1.6 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb has the wrong version (1.3.4) installed.
    - Installation request for mongodb/mongodb ^1.5 -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.6.x-dev, v1.5.x-dev].`

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    `- /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-igbinary.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-mongodb.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-msgpack.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-zip.ini
    - /etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/25-memcached.ini`

You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Answer (score -1):

`composer require jenssegers/mongodb --ignore-platform-reqs`

Comment: `--ignore-platform-reqs` просто проигнорирует сообщения, а что бы работал mongo вам нужно установить расширение для php https://stackoverflow.com/a/53593934/12596215